# Full outer join. brain dumps

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I just bought a dump questions of SQL certification but I think they are the most wrong. Can you help me to tell if I am right here?

[image: this is the question saying that is C]

[image: This is my answer. I create the tables and everything to test it]

I don't know maybe I didn't understand the question.
Plus: Do you have any good piece of advice to give me to study to the SQL certification? Good brain dump? thanks

Comment: You should follow these guidelines (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable) here in SO  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I would go with answer A).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show as much reasoning/work as you can. Explain how you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not suitable since the requirement is:

> no department IDs if they do not have any courses.

This means C) and D) are out of the question.

Now, B) shows all `DEPARTMENT` regardless they have course or not. Again this one contradicts the requirement above.

Finally A) shows all `COURSE_DETAILS` regardless they have a department or not. This one does what is asked.